# How to prove this circumcircle question

Tags: geometry

If H is the orthocentre of triangle ABC and AH meets BC at D and the circumcircle at E,then prove that HD=DE

Comment: Please consider the answer that you have received. If you are not satisfied with it, please provide comment. If you are OK, upvote/accept the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at triangles $\triangle CDH$ and $\triangle CDE$.

$\angle CDH=\angle CDE=90^\circ\tag{1}$

$\angle HCD=\angle BAE$ because these two angles have perpendicular legs.

On the other side $\angle BAE=\angle BCE$ because these are inscribed angles over the same arc. Consequentially:

$\angle HCD=\angle BCE=\angle DCE\tag{2}$

Taking (1) and (2) into account, triangles $\triangle CDH$ and $\triangle CDE$ are congruent by SAS.

It follows immediately that $DH=DE$.

Comment: Can you explain how angles HDC and BAE are equal?

Comment: Oh I have realised how.